# Tag errors when using :h

Tags: vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I have ctags installed on my machine through Homebrew, but I haven't generated any tags files. However, when running the command `:h word` I get the following two errors:

```
E432: Tags file not sorted: /usr/local/share/vim/vim81/doc/tags
E426: tag not found: b:match_word@en
```

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this. Is there a default tags file included with Vim for the help system? I have the youcompleteme plugin installed, would that mess with tag functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrading to macOS Calatina gave me the same issue with the help in vim. To fix the problem, I just upgraded vim.

```
brew upgrade vim
```

Output:

vim 8.1.2100 -> 8.1.2250

Comment: `Error: vim not installed`

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252433/how-to-upgrade-system-default-vim

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using MacOS Catalina? In that case there seems to be a bug with the tags file sorting.

Open Vim Issues:
[5061](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/5061)
[5039](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5039)

Fixed by by [PR 955](https://github.com/StephenWall/vim/pull/955) in [v8.2.0314](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.0314)

Check also similar bug reports for MacVim and Neovim.

MacOS Catalina ships with v8.1 which does not include the patch

```sh
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Dec 13 2019 14:45:40)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1312
```

Comment: Catalina FFS. As of Nov 8, you can download a nightly neovim for macos which has been patched, from here https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/nightly

Comment: It is also patched in Macvim now.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a default tags file included with Vim for the help system?

Yes, it should work out-of-the-box. But you can always recreate them (note that write privilege is required):

```
:helptags $VIMRUNTIME/doc
```

Alternatively, you can recreate all tags at once, including all installed plugins, with `:helptags ALL`.